# Simplifying this complex ternary operator in simple working code

Tags: javascript

I am refactoring [this piece of code](https://github.com/jashkenas/docco/blob/d3da6e9b59aeaf197b80c3d6c982de754a14832a/docco.js#L151-L155).

The main part I am fixing is:

```
for (i = j = 0, len = lines.length; j < len; i = ++j) {
  line = lines[i];
  lines[i] = maybeCode && (match = /^([ ]{4}|[ ]{0,3}\t)/.exec(line)) ? (isText = false, line.slice(match[0].length)) : (maybeCode = /^\s*$/.test(line)) ? isText ? lang.symbol : '' : (isText = true, lang.symbol + ' ' + line);
}
```

(I know, right?)
The goal of the function is simple: starting from an array if "lines" in Markdown format, it needs to produce working Coffeescript code.

So, for example this string:

```
This is text

The point of this exercise is to turn this MD file into a compilable
coffeescript code -- where the code bits are indented by three spaces.

So, this is code:

  document = (options = {}, callback) ->
    config = configure options
    Code can have an empty line.

    blah

And then there is text again
```

Should become:

```
# This is text
#
# The point if this exercis is to turn this MD file into a compilable
# coffeescript code -- where the code bits are indented by three spaces.
#
# So, this is code:
#
document = (options = {}, callback) ->
  config = configure options
  Code can have an empty line.

  blah

# And then there is text again.
```

The idea is that:

- Any text that is indented by four spaces becomes "pure code" (the leading spaces are taken away)
- Any text that doesn't have indentation spaces become a comment (yes, coffeescript has `#` as one line comments

The tricky part is in empty lines. If they happen between "code" (that is, indented stuff), they should be just blank lines. If they happen between indented text, they should have a leading `#` (since they are an empty line in the text which then becomes documentation).

What follows is a working script with the way I "evolved" the beast:

- `originalCode()` is the code as it was. It works, but it's a huge impossible to maintain one-liner
- `fixedConditional()` is the same code as above, where I at least worked out how the ternary operators nested into each other
- `ternaryIntoIf()` is the conversion of the existing ternary operators into IFs
- `fullRewrite()` is my full rewrite.

My problem is that I just *cannot* get my head around the `ternaryIntoIf()` function (which should be really easy to read) with `maybeCode` testing for empty lines, and *two* different flags, `isText` and `maybeCode`, to manage the possible case with an empty line...

The real question is: **Am I missing anything in terms of what the original code does?** Do those two flags cover a case that I didn't think about? Am I missing something?

Here is the full working code

`````
var startingLines = `This is text

The point if this exercis is to turn this MD file into a compilable
coffeescript code -- where the code bits are indented by three spaces.

So, this is code:

    document = (options = {}, callback) ->
      config = configure options
      Code can have an empty line.

      blah

And then there is text again.`.split(/\n/)

var lang = { symbol: '#' }

function originalCode (startingLines) {
  var isText, maybeCode, match
  var line, i, j, len
  var lines = [ ...startingLines ]
  isText = maybeCode = true

  for (i = j = 0, len = lines.length; j < len; i = ++j) {
    line = lines[i]
    lines[i] = maybeCode && (match = /^([ ]{4}|[ ]{0,3}\t)/.exec(line)) ? (isText = false, line.slice(match[0].length)) : (maybeCode = /^\s*$/.test(line)) ? isText ? lang.symbol : '' : (isText = true, lang.symbol + ' ' + line);
  }
  return lines.join('\n')
}


function fixedConditional (startingLines) {
  var isText, maybeCode, match
  var lines = [ ...startingLines ]
  isText = maybeCode = true

  for (let i in lines) {
    let line = lines[i]
    lines[i] = maybeCode && (match = /^([ ]{4}|[ ]{0,3}\t)/.exec(line))
      ? (isText = false, line.slice(match[0].length))
      : (maybeCode = /^\s*$/.test(line))
        ? isText ? lang.symbol : ''
        : (isText = true, lang.symbol + ' ' + line)
  }
  return lines.join('\n')
}

function ternaryIntoIf (startingLines) {
  var isText, maybeCode, match
  var lines = [ ...startingLines ]
  isText = maybeCode = true

  for (let i in lines) {
    let line = lines[i]
    if (maybeCode && (match = /^([ ]{4}|[ ]{0,3}\t)/.exec(line))) {
      isText = false
      lines[i] = line.slice(match[0].length)
    } else {
      maybeCode = /^\s*$/.test(line)
      if (maybeCode) {
        lines[i] = isText ? lang.symbol : ''
      } else {
        isText = true
        lines[i] = lang.symbol + ' ' + line
      }
    }
  }
  return lines.join('\n')
}

function fullRewrite (startingLines) {
  var lines = [ ...startingLines ]
  var match
  var markdownIndented = /^([ ]{4}|[ ]{0,3}\t)/
  var inCode = lines[0] && markdownIndented.exec(lines[0])

  for (let i in lines) {
    let line = lines[i]
    var emptyLine = /^\s*$/.test(line)
    if (emptyLine) {
      lines[i] = inCode ? '' : lang.symbol
    } else {
      inCode = (match = markdownIndented.exec(line))
      lines[i] = inCode
        ? line.slice(match[0].length)
        : lang.symbol + ' ' + line
    }
  }
  return lines.join('\n')
}

console.log('\n\nOriginal code')
console.log(originalCode(startingLines))

console.log('\n\nConditional fixed, better cycle')
console.log(fixedConditional(startingLines))

console.log('\n\nTernary into if')
console.log(ternaryIntoIf(startingLines))

console.log('\n\nFULL REWRITE')
console.log(fullRewrite(startingLines))
````
`````

Comment: We can review your code _fullRewrite_, but not the original code I'm afraid. Only code written by you is subject to review.

Comment: `ternaryIntoIf()` is a near-total rewrites too... The others are to show how I got there, and what the original code is supposed to do

Comment: Your question _Am I missing anything in terms of what the original code does?_ asks about code not written by you, which you don't fully understand. You also don't know whether your rewrite accounts for all edge cases of the original code.  Not knowing whether your code works as intended is also off-topic for this site. Check our help center for more details: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I did a code review on open source code, and spent nearly 1 hour writing my post. If it doesn't fit this site, downvote it, I will delete it, whatever. But it looks to me like a well posed, legitimate question.

Comment: I upvoted and flagged your question shortly after you posted it. I upvoted because it does look like you have invested some time into it. Unfortunately, I had to flag it because it's off-topic for this site.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound cranky.

Comment: Don't worry about it. :)